# PHP texto do banco para html

Tags: php, html

Estou com problema para retornar texto com formatação HTML para a *view*. Preciso retorna-lo com quebra de linhas. Tentei também coloca-lo sem as *tags* HTML no banco e depois utilizei a função `nl2br()` que transforma `/n` na *tag* `<br>`, porém em ambos os casos ele retorna com `""` aspas entre o texto como está na imagem abaixo do firebug. Tentei com diferentes funções PHP para retirar as aspas, mas sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se você quiser tirar essas aspas aí você terá que fazer assim:

```
 trim(nl2br($texto));
```

A não ser que na hora que você está imprimindo a variável você tenha feito assim:

```
<div>
   <?php echo  nl2br($texto); ?>
</div>
```

Porque nesse caso, a quebra de linha dada na div conta como espaço (o que gera aquelas aspas no interpretador do `firebug`).

No caso, você pode fazer assim:

```
<div><?php echo trim(nl2br($texto)) ?></div>
```

Fiz o seguinte teste para você verificar que meus dois últimos exemplos possuem diferenças:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
<div>Meu nome é Wallace</div>
<?php var_dump(ob_get_clean()) ?>

<?php ob_start() ?>
<div>
    Meu nome é Wallace
</div>
<?php var_dump(ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

Os resultados são:

```
string(31) "<div>Meu nome é Wallace</div>
"

string(34) "<div>
    Meu nome é Wallace
</div>
"
```

Perceba aí que essas quebras de linha são processadas como conteúdo da string.

A primeira string ficou com a aspa em baixo porque precisei dar uma quebra de linha para colocar o `var_dump(ob_get_clean())`

Comment: Pensei nisso também, mas fiquei na dúvida se era a maneira correta hehe

Comment: +1 ta ligeiro hein hsausha

Comment: também uso essa forma, porque não seria correta? @DiegoFelipe

Comment: Vou deixar a resposta mais completa. Aguardem os prints

Comment: @Bia não que não fosse a forma correta, fora de mim afirmar isso. Apenas fiquei na dúvida se era a melhor forma, mas pelas explicações do Wallace, tá mais que provado :)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada.

Answer (score 2):

Se não for visível no seu html estas aspas duplas a explicação delas aparecerem no seu element inspector é simples: Organização do texto.

Como citado nesta resposta : [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608899/chrome-adding-quotes-to-html)

> **Original**
>
> This is just the way that chrome presents the text node content in the
> element inspector. You can see white-space better this way. The quotes
> are purely virtual.
>
> **Tradução**
>
> Esta é apenas a maneira que o Chrome apresenta o conteúdo do nó de
> texto no Inspetor de elemento. Você pode visualizar melhor assim. As citações são puramente virtual.

Caso exista as aspas no seu html use trim para remove-las:

**Exemplo:**

```
$str = '"Hello"';
echo trim($str, '"'); // saída: Hello
```

Comment: Estamos nesse caso pressupondo que o problema seja as àspas salvas no banco. Mas ainda acho que não é isso. As aspas não são das palavras e sim do interpretador do `firebug`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters foi o que eu pensei, estou acostumado a utilizar apenas o Firebug no mozilla, utilizei o Inspecionar Elemento do Chrome e meus textos também possuem Aspas duplas, parece que é do programa mesmo, se as aspas não aparecerem na visualização ela não deverá se preocupar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema não é com a função `nl2br`. Verifique a saída antes de aplicar a função para ter certeza. Parece também que o `firebug` coloca aspas automaticamente no console quando se trata de mais de uma linha, para melhorar a visualização.

Comment: +1 Apenas não compreendo o por que de tantos negativos, se vocês  verem nesta resposta do SOEN  perceberam que o element inspector age assim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608899/chrome-adding-quotes-to-html

Comment: Oi amigo, obrigado pela referência. Não se trata de negativos em relação ao firebug. A questão é identificar se a situação apresentada é um "problema" (resposta com aspas a partir do PHP), e **resolvê-lo**, ou apenas um comportamento do firebug (resposta sem aspas do PHP, apresentado com aspas no console).